# Optimize the Authentication in JSF + JPA web application

Tags: java, security, authentication

I have a JSF + JPA web application where login mechanism is as follows.

1. User Names are encrypted
2. Passwords are Hashed
3. Used Jasypt
4. When a user try to login, all the users are taken for a loop.
5. The user name of every user is decrypted and matched with the entered user name.
6. If that matches, the password is hashed and checked with the stored hased password.

In another application where the number of users are expected to be high, I filter users from the first three letters, which is stored as a separate field.

I will be grateful to you if you can point out the sub optimal methodology I have used and guide me the correct action.

The Controller concerned with the Encryption is listed

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.jasypt.util.password.BasicPasswordEncryptor;
import org.jasypt.util.text.BasicTextEncryptor;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SecurityController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public SecurityController() {
}

public String encrypt(String word) {
    BasicTextEncryptor en = new BasicTextEncryptor();
    en.setPassword("health");
    try {
        return en.encrypt(word);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public String hash(String word) {
    try {
        BasicPasswordEncryptor en = new BasicPasswordEncryptor();
        return en.encryptPassword(word);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public boolean matchPassword(String planePassword, String encryptedPassword) {
    BasicPasswordEncryptor en = new BasicPasswordEncryptor();
    return en.checkPassword(planePassword, encryptedPassword);
}

public String decrypt(String word) {
    BasicTextEncryptor en = new BasicTextEncryptor();
    en.setPassword("health");
    try {
        return en.decrypt(word);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }

    }
}
```

This his how I check the autnetication.

```
private boolean checkUsers() {
    String temSQL;
    temSQL = "SELECT u FROM WebUser u WHERE u.retired = false";
    List<WebUser> allUsers = getFacede().findBySQL(temSQL);
    for (WebUser u : allUsers) {
        if (getSecurityController().decrypt(u.getName()).equalsIgnoreCase(userName)) {
            if (getSecurityController().matchPassword(passord, u.getWebUserPassword())) {
                setLoggedUser(u);
                setLogged(Boolean.TRUE);
                setActivated(u.isActivated());
                setRole(u.getRole());
                getMessageController().setDefLocale(u.getDefLocale());
                getMeController().createMenu();
                getWebUserBean().setLoggedUser(u);
                UtilityController.addSuccessMessage("Logged successfully");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: First question, why encrypt the user names?

Comment: I though of a situation where an attacker who can read the database likely can intercept the unencrypted user names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user names are sensitive;

- Hash the username with a static salt (single salt for the system, but should be enough to protect the username)
- Hash the password with a dynamic salt (individual for every user) that is saved along with the password in the database.

When a user tries to log in;

- Hash his username given at login using the static salt and search for the result in the database. This will be an exact match search that will give a single result (or none if the username does not exist)
- Get the dynamic salt from the found row, and hash his password given at login using it. If it matches the hashed password in the found database row, let the user in.

Given this security, no one (not even you) can list all user names in the system. If you know a user name, you can verify its existence and find the user.